# Read_ Write Excel File errors with POI API 4.1.0

Tags: java, apache-poi

I keep getting following errors:

```
XSSFHyperlink link=createHelper.createHyperlink(XSSFHyperlink.Link_FILE);
```

Red line under 
Link_FILE 
"Link_FILE can not be resoved or this is not a file" error message.

```
style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_40_PERCENT.index);
style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

Red line under GREY_40_PERCENT &
Red line under  SOLID_FOREGROUND.

```
style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_40_PERCENT.index);
style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.NO_FILL);
```

Red line under

GREY_40_PERCENT and
NO_FILE

Comment: Please read `API` doc. [CreationHelper.createHyperlink](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CreationHelper.html#createHyperlink-org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.HyperlinkType-) needs a [HyperlinkType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/common/usermodel/HyperlinkType.html).

Comment: The color indexes are now in [HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/util/HSSFColor.HSSFColorPredefined.html) or in [IndexedColors](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/IndexedColors.html).
[CellStyle.setFillPattern](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setFillPattern-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType-) needs a [FillPatternType](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FillPatternType.html).